# Memory Leak (char[])

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

When I run my program, it can run for a while, then all of the sudden, it experiences a huge memory leak. I traced it out using a snapshot of the heap when it crashed, and I have a mysterious char[] with the size of 232,023,801 Bytes. The minutes preceding crash have no unusual behavior until then. The only places where I use char arrays is in the following piece of code:

```
string ReadString(DWORD64 addr) {

    char* buffer = new char[128];

    bool validChar = true;
    for (int c = 0; c < 128 && validChar; c++) {
        buffer[c] = Mem.Read<char>(addr+ (0x1 * c), sizeof(char));
        if (!isalnum(buffer[c]) && !ispunct(buffer[c]))
            validChar = false;
    }
    string ret= string(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;
    return ret;
}
```

All this code should be doing is reading a few characters from memory, saving the char array to a string, cleaning up the array, and returning the string. How is the memory leak originating from here? Or does the char[] in the heap snapshot potentially point to another issue?

Comment: There is no leak in this code (unless `Mem.Read()` or `string()` throw an exception), let alone anything that allocates 221K of memory. To avoid any possible leaking, you should use a `std::vector<char>` instead of a `char[]`. Or, just read from memory directly into the `std::string` that you return.

Comment: And never use bare new a delete in code like this. If you're using C++, you should be adhering to RAII

Comment: What else could cause an enormous char[] to form and fill the heap if no other char[] are made throughout the code?

Comment: @user1939991: what makes you think there is any `char[]` at all? Or even a single `char[]`?  If you are just looking at raw memory, it could represent *literally anything*.  To diagnose a memory leak, you need to trace your app's individual allocations and frees.  Only your app's memory manager library can do that reliably, since it is the one managing those operations, so only it knows what constitutes a real leak. For instance, maybe freed memory is cached for later reuse? You don't know, it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @user1939991 And are you sure it's a single array, and not 232,023,801 bytes total of leaked character arrays?

Comment: Why, ohh why, are you not using smart pointers in this day and age?

Comment: `string(buffer)` expects a null-terminated string, assuming this is `std::string`. `buffer` doesn't seem to be null-terminated, so this could conceivably allocate a lot of memory or crash.

Comment: I'll have to read up on smart pointers -- i'm still rather new to C++. I took a heap snapshot, and it listed a char[] under object type with a count of 1 and a size of 232,023,801 bytes. I might be interpreting this wrong, though.

Comment: There's no reason to use `new/delete` here. Just declare a local array. Or declare a `std::string` and append each character to it, rather than using the temporary array.

Comment: @interjay That's almost certainly the problem, post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for your help! I am still learning C++, and I am using bad habits that I formed while using Java, as it took care of most of the memory management for me.

Comment: `(0x1 * c)`.  Ummm.

Comment: Haha, that was leftover from my other function which used wchar and had a spacing of 0x2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `string` here is `std::string`:

You call `string(buffer)` which assumes that `buffer` is 0-terminated and allocates a new string. But your code doesn't ensure that `buffer` is actually 0-terminated, so this can cause undefined behavior, including potentially crashing or allocating too much memory for the string.

You probably want to use the `string(buffer, size)` constructor instead, which doesn't require `buffer` to be 0-terminated.

I'd also recommend avoiding the manual `new`/`delete`. One way to do this is to create an empty string and `push_back` the characters you read to it. This avoid the need for `buffer`.